# npm info takes 70 seconds for info

Tags: cordova, cmd, npm

I'm developing a Java application which needs to access information from the cordova version installed on the machine. I'm doing this by reading the command line output of `cordova -v` and it works fine. However I also need something from the output of `npm info cordova`. It worked well at first but suddenly out of no apparent reason npm now takes about 70 seconds to return the info. Apparently this isn't sufficient for a query which should only return some basic text. So my questions are:

- Could there be any reason why it takes so long/any fix for that?
- Is there a better way obtaining this information programmatically without knowing the directory cordova is installed in?

If additional information is needed please tell me so and I'll try my best.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comand [npm info [package]](https://www.npmjs.com/package/package-info) **request** current informations about the package  **online**. It does not return the current version on your local device.

> npm info [...] Fetches the information directly from the registry [...]

So your 70 second delay is caused because the request from the server take so long.

If you want check your **local version of cordova** use this command in your device terminal:

```
cordova -v
```

Comment: i see your point and agree that this is no issue of my machine. However it kinda puzzles me that the delay is so consistent at roughly 70 seconds